# Restrict Visual Studio Code -> Deploy to function app

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, deployment, continuous-integration, azure-function-app

Deploying code directly to a function app through visual studio code extension is really handy feature but we want to restrict our team using this feature to follow strict CI/CD pipeline.

Is there any way we can block deployment to Function App through Visual Studio Code and allow deployment only through CI/CD pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

It's a personal choice of a developer and sort of a practice that you need to follow within your team. There is no way to restrict publishing from VScode!